# why my addLoadEvent just the first js file executes?

Tags: dom

```
function addLoadEvent (func) {
let oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload !== 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
} else {
    window.onload = function () {
        oldonload();
        func();
    }
}
```

this addLoadEvent is right

```
<script src="addLoadEvent.js"></script>
<script src="getAbbreviation.js"></script>
<script src="getCitation.js"></script>
```

it just the "getAbbreviation.js" works

Comment: You might want to post all of your other files' code as well, there might be uncaught issues.

Comment: Here is the complete files: https://github.com/ORDOABCHAOWT/Web-Front-end-Honeypot/tree/master/Substentiation